# Is it possible to import class method without instantiating class?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, import, python-2.x

Having class located somewhere in my_module.py

I can access his method like this

```
from .my_module import Mailer

mailer = Mailer()
mailer.do_stuff()
```

But if I can import just `do_stuff` method from class? If so, can I import not only static methods?

Comment: If you have a static method that you want to use separately from the class, *make it a function*. What do you mean by *"initialising"*? You can access class and static methods without creating an instance (`Mailer.do_stuff()`), but not without initialising the class object (because until that happens *they don't exist*).

Comment: Yep, you've got it, I meant instantiation of class

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can access *class* and *static* methods on the class, without creating an instance. For example, take the following demo class:

```
class Demo(object):

    def instance_method(self):
        print "Called an instance method"

    @classmethod
    def class_method(cls):
        print "Called a class method"

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        print "Called a static method"
```

Now we can call two of those methods directly on the class:

```
>>> Demo.class_method()
Called a class method
>>> Demo.static_method()
Called a static method
```

But we can't call the *instance* method, as we don't have an instance for the `self` argument:

```
>>> Demo.instance_method()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    Demo.instance_method()
TypeError: unbound method instance_method() must be called with Demo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

You can call all three types of method on an instance:

```
>>> instance = Demo()
>>> instance.class_method()
Called a class method
>>> instance.static_method()
Called a static method
>>> instance.instance_method()
Called an instance method
```

---

Note that static methods don't use any class or instance attributes, therefore they are pretty much identical to functions. If you find yourself wanting to call a function without referencing the class or an instance, just factor it out to a function.

Comment: In Python 3, you can certainly call `Demo.instance_method`, if you provide it with an object.